# How to get array in class component to another file in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

The real situation is that I want to get the value of radio button in one file and let them show in another file, therefore I can let user know what they select before.

The code that use select the radio button:

```
class Usurvey extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      uid: uuid.v1(),
      studentName: '',
      answers: {
        answer1: '',
        answer2: '',
        answer3: ''
      },
      isSubmitted: false
    };
    this.nameSubmit = this.nameSubmit.bind(this);
    this.answerSelected = this.answerSelected.bind(this);
    this.questionSubmit = this.questionSubmit.bind(this);
  }
render(){
<form onSubmit={this.questionSubmit}>
          <div className="card">
          <div className="video">
          <ReactPlayer  url={Array[0].url} />
          </div>       
              <label>Do you think the video is fake or real? </label> <br />
              <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="real" onChange={this.answerSelected} />Real
              <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="fake" onChange={this.answerSelected} />Fake
            </div>

            <div className="card">
            <div className="video">
          <ReactPlayer  url={Array[0].url} />
          </div>     
              <label>Do you think the video is fake or real? </label> <br />
              <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="real" onChange={this.answerSelected} />Real
              <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="fake" onChange={this.answerSelected} />Fake
            </div>
return(
      <div>
        {studentName}
        {questions}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Usurvey;
```

The code file I want to input the value of radio button.

```
'use strict'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import Array from '../Array';
import Usurvey from '../Usurvey2';


export default () => {

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="video">
          <ReactPlayer  url={Array[0].url} playing/>
          <div>
              <p>Your guess: </p>
               <p>{Usurvey.props.Answer[0]}</p> 
               <p>Right Answer:</p>
               <p>{Array[0].name}</p>
          </div> 

          </div>   

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Now I tried to import the Usurvey from the last file and use prop to get  answer, but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Props are not static or hardcoded data that can be accessed by just import the file. Moreover, this is not a way to pass props from a parent component to a child component.

Either you need to lift up the state in `Usurvey` component to its parent component from where you can pass it to the component where you want the radio button's value.

Or you can pass onSubmit from handler as a prop to `Usurvey` component from its parent component. The parent component will store the form data and pass it to the required component.

Or if both the component are at a different level of hierarchy then you can also use redux instead of passing it to each component in the path.

You can read more about components and props over [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

> Edit

```js
class ParentComponent extends Component {

  state = {
     submittedQuestion: {} // depending on your logic you can store all the 
                              questions or just one.
  }

  onQuestionSubmit = () => {
     // store data in state.
  }

  render (){
   const {submittedQuestion} = this.state;
   return (

     <Usurvey onQuestionSubmit={this.onQuestionSubmit} />
     <QuestionSubmittedView submittedQuestion={submittedQuestion}/>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you going through react's state, props and life cycle first.

Comment: I do not know whether you could write code: Or you can pass onSubmit from handler as a prop to Usurvey component from its parent component. The parent component will store the form data and pass it to the required component. How can I achieve it?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-architecture-zoxlf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You can see two files, one is Usurvey2.js, one is in the Component_T3 called StepOne.js

Comment: Thanks. I need time to consume it. Appreciated.